# Why is decltype necessary in an "auto returning" function?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, decltype

Consider [this code](http://ideone.com/eDHI42) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto add(T1 l, T2 r) -> decltype(l + r){
    return l + r;
}

class C {};

class B {};

class A {
public:
    C operator+(const B& b) {
        C c;
        return c;
    }
};


int main() {
    // Using add()
    A a;
    B b;
    auto c = add(a, b);

    cout << typeid(a).name() << endl;
    cout << typeid(b).name() << endl;
    cout << typeid(c).name() << endl;
    cout << endl;

    // Doing the same thing but not on a function
    A a2;
    B b2;
    auto c2 = a2 + b2;

    cout << typeid(a2).name() << endl;
    cout << typeid(b2).name() << endl;
    cout << typeid(c2).name() << endl;
}
```

I just have a very simple question: why do I need to put `decltype()` in the postfix return type of `add()` unlike in the second method (the one that doesn't use `add()`)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> why do I need to put decltype() in the postfix return type of add() unlike in the second method (the one that doesn't use add())?

Because that's part of the rules of C++. The parser is run left-to-right; for the most part, if an identifier hasn't been reached yet, the parser doesn't know about it. Identifiers like the function parameters.

So if you use an expression to determine the type of the return value, and that expression uses the parameters in some way, you must put the return type after the function arguments.

> But my point is, why can't the compiler automatically deduce the return type when it knows that A + B returns C?

Because those are the rules of C++: a function must have a return type specified directly in the function declaration. The compiler isn't allowed to deduce it.

[Yet.](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2012/n3386.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link, is it part of mainline gcc ?

Comment: @MatthieuM.: I doubt it. It's mostly a proof-of-concept, as the specific semantics still need to be nailed down.

Answer (score 1):

> why do I need to put decltype() in the postfix return type of add()

Because you declared the return type of the template function as `auto`, and you need to specify somehow the return type after function's declaration.

You could have also specified it like this :

```
auto add(T1 l, T2 r) -> C
```

but that wouldn't work very well if you pass for example integers to that function.

I do not see the 2nd add function, but if you mean `operator+`, then you specified the return type for it.

Comment: Of course I specified the operator for `A + B` to explicitly return `C`. But my point is, why can't the compiler automatically deduce the return type when it knows that `A + B` returns `C`?

Comment: @MarkGarcia There is a difference between "why can't .." and "why isn't it allowed/mandated/prohibited in the spec .."

Comment: @pst You're right. But there is an implication that when the question "why can't the compiler..." also means "why isn't it allowed in the spec?"

Comment: @MarkGarcia Cost and cost/benefit.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to - you can put anything in the return type specification that is a type. If your question is "why can't the compiler deduce the correct type for me?": I a few cases, it could, but at least it needs to see the definition. There are cases where the compiler already *does* deduce the return type: in lambdas that consist of a single return statement

```
   auto l = [](int i) { return i>0; };
```

IIRC there are ambitions to loosen the restrictions on those return type declarations, e.g. to allow one-liner functions with only the auto return type like you are suggesting.